# Two Tables, Person + Descendant, both have a cellular phone column, database mechanism to avoid duplicates across both tables?

Tags: database, database-design, duplicates, unique, foreign-key-relationship

How would you maintain duplicate phone numbers across both tables?

In writing this, I realized why not separate the mobile phone number column into a separate table, and use foreign key constraints where the mobile phone number table stores the ph# and a key column that references the unique key in both the person and descendants key column.  That way I can create a constraint on the mobile phone number table to not store duplicates for the ph# column.

Is this the only possible solution or are there other ways to go about it?  I think this would be the preferred solution, correct?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

yes this is a good solution. The table storing the numbers can store each phone number once and you use the primary key of that table as a foreign key in others just as you have said.